# Issue in date conversion in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my @query I am putting the date in MM-DD-YYYY format. e.g., 01-22-2016. Now I want to search the dates from messages table with that date how can I do. I had added the query:

```
Message.includes(:user)
  .select('messages.*, users.name')
  .where(
    "users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at.srtftime(\"%Y-%m-%d\") = ?",
    "%#{@query}%",
    "%#{@query}%",
    Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")
  )
```

But I am getting the issue for that:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "%Y-%m-%d" does not exist
```

I had also added the query as:

```
Message.includes(:user)
  .select('messages.*, users.name')
  .where(
    "users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at.srtftime("%Y-%m-%d") = ?",
    "%#{@query}%",
    "%#{@query}%",
    Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")
  )
```

But in that the error is coming as: `unknown type of %string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment on @Amadan's answer:

> If I don't convert my `message.created_at` then I am getting blank result.
>
> ```
> Message.includes(:user)
>   .select('messages.*, users.name')
>   .where(
>     "users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at = ?",
>     "%#{@query}%",
>     "%#{@query}%",
>     Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")
> )
> ```

This will produce a query with (among others) a condition like this:

```
messages.created_at = '2016-01-29 00:00:00'
```

It should be apparent why this won't work.
`messages.created_at` is a timestamp, and unless the record just happens to have been created at midnight, that equality comparison is going to fail.

What you need to do is compare the *date part* of `messages.created_at` to the date from the query. To get the date part of a timestamp in PostgreSQL, you can use either the `date()` function or the `::date` suffix:

```
Message.includes(:user)
  .select('messages.*, users.name')
  .where(
    "messages.created_at::date = ?",
    Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you don't have dates stored in the database in `VARCHAR` columns, but `DATETIME` or equivalent. Don't convert to `String`, let ActiveRecord handle dates for you: `messages.created_at = ?`.

Comment: Actually I have a search text field at the top in which user can search by name, email or date. For date we have specified the format as: MM-DD-YYYY. So the result is coming in string.

Comment: In my database created_at is stored in this format: 2015-10-07 12:43:35.273415

Comment: That only says what the output is like. What do you have in your database schema? What does your `CREATE TABLE` look like? And if you have a date coming in from a user as a `String`, convert that into `DateTime` in your controller's action, your model should never see a `String` there.

Comment: created_at has datatype as timestamp without timezone. I have converted my @query using: Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y"). I also want to convert my message.created_at in the same format and then compare them. But I am getting error for the same

Comment: What I am saying is, you don't need to convert `message.created_at`. It is a  timestamp; your DBMS is smart enough to compare two timestamps. If your `@query` is a `Date`, `DateTime` or similar, ActiveRecord is smart enough to format it in such a way that your DBMS will understand it as a timestamp.

Comment: If I don't convert my message.created_at then I am getting blank result. Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at = ?" ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y"))